# How to protect the encryption key from reverse engineering?

Tags: security, aes, encryption-symmetric, rijndael

My software is using AES Rijndael.

I am using a SHA-256 hash to generate a key from a string with an arbitrary length, and then passing this as both the private and public key since in this instance I do not need to differentiate between the two.

How do I protect my key from being hacked out of the executable?

I know not to use a literal but instead generate the key at runtime with some predetermined steps, but all the same the key will still be in memory right before its sent on to the AES initialization function and so can quite easily be retrieved then.

AES is obviously very secure, but what good does that do me if someone breaks the executable instead?

Is there some common practise when solving this problem?

Comment: What exactly are you worried about? Is the key constant (as computed from a string embedded in the executable)? It's pretty unclear.

Comment: All I am doing is generating a string at runtime which is used as the key, but obviously always the same string. The whole point is to avoid storing the key as a string literal in the program, but rather generate it on the fly. This does not prevent people from simply setting a breakpoint right before the encryption initialization call and inspecting memory, however. My main question is how I might make this more secure so that it is not as easy to extract the key during execution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can't be done. This is the basic problem with e.g. DRM scheme's on PC's: they need to have the key in memory, so it can be extracted. You can maybe obscure it while it is not in use, but that's about it. And if your application is popular and distributed, then somebody *will* crack you delicious scheme. That's why some companies use dongles or TPM chips for high value applications.

Comment: Of course, if you have control over your execution environment, you can do things like protect your PC from outside access, encrypting your virtual memory pool and other hardening techniques.

Answer (score 3):

There is something - very complex in mathematical theory - called "whitebox cryptography". In this case, the AES algorithm is modified in a way, that it builds up the secret during encryption. I do not know exactly, how this is achieved, but this one does not need to have a initialized secret, but the secret is part of the algorithm.
An attacker might see, that your AES implementation is a bit "different" but at no time in execution the key is visible in memory. The only chance an attacker will have, is to copy the whole whitebox code but it is really hard to reverse engineer this - he would just be able to use it. Anyway depending on the way you use the AES, this might be enough to break in.

Comment: Yes, it's been years since this question.
Could you add a few articles on this topic?